# running sum with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

I have the following data in a table:

```
col1
---
1
2
5
9
10
```

I want to update `col2` in the table with the running sum of the difference between `col1` and the previous value of `col1` minus 1

```
col2 = col2.prev + col1 - col1.prev - 1
```

The result would be:

```
col1  |  col2
--------------
  1   |  0
  2   |  0
  5   |  2
  9   |  5
 10   |  5
```

I tried using a window function:

```
SELECT sum(col1 - lag(col1) OVER (ORDER BY col1) - 1) AS col2 FROM table1
```

But this is not allowed - ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls

Is there another way I can accomplish this? I know I could easily write a function to loop through the rows but I get the impression from what I've read that this method is not efficient and discouraged in most cases. Please correct me if I have the wrong impression.

Comment: can you confirm the output in COL2 should be- 00255 OR 00355

Comment: it is 00255 - since 0+5-2-1=2, 2+9-5-1=5, 5+10-9-1=5, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls

This error message is displayed because it is not permitted to apply an aggregate function on a column generated through a windowed expression. Nor is it permitted to apply a second windowed expression. The solution is to simply wrap the result in a cte & apply the second windowed expression in a subsequent select statement.

```
WITH mytable(col1) AS (
VALUES (1), (2), (5), (9), (10)
)
, lagdiff AS (
  SELECT
    col1
  , COALESCE(col1 - lag(col1) OVER (ORDER BY col1) - 1, 0) col2_
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT
  col1
, SUM(col2_) OVER (ORDER BY col1) col2
FROM lagdiff
```

Produces Output:

```
 col1 | col2
------+------
    1 |    0
    2 |    0
    5 |    2
    9 |    5
   10 |    5
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by cte?

Comment: cte is an initialism for common table expression, which is a sub query that sits ahead of the main query rather than directly in the from clause.